# Server RAM acting as HDD

Tags: ubuntu, centos, memory, ssd

I've some software that wants access to a very fast disk.  I could buy an SSD, but my server has approx 64GB of ram *spare*.  Is it possible to use a portion of that unused RAM to create and mount a virtual disk?

I'm using either Ubuntu or CentOS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tmpfs might help:

```
mount -t tmpfs -osize=4g tmpfs /mountpoint
```

You'll lose whatever is there if you reboot, though.  It may be okay for temporary files, but it is not a replacement for an SSD.

Answer (score 3):

Any unused RAM will be automatically allocated for caching reads / buffering writes - and you get the added advantage that its automatically flushed to disk. Certainly there will be times (e.g. after a reboot) when the cache might benefit from being primed - but that's just a matter of reading all the files.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably use `/dev/shm` for this, as long as the files saved are temporary. Ubuntu apparently auto-mounts this filesystem. See [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/45342/when-should-i-use-dev-shm-and-when-should-i-use-tmp).

Alternatively you can create a custom ramdisk this way:

```
mount -t tmpfs -o size=SIZE tmpfs /where/to/mount
```

As `SIZE` you can specify either a size in K, M or G or a percentage of physical RAM (ie `size=50%`).